# NSHTTPURLResponse not recognizing the custom http response code

Tags: java, objective-c, ios, spring, ios5

We have a restful service layer implemented using Java Spring which has below statements to notify the client that there is some error

```
     response.setStatus(1024);
```

Trying to access the url from browser shows that backend returns 1024 as status

In the iPhone application, we are using NSURLConnection to asynchronously download some information from server. Below is the code for didReceiveResponse

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
    {
      NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
      responseStatusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];
      NSLog(@"responseStatusCode ==%i",responseStatusCode);
      [self.responseData setLength:0];
    }
```

Above code always returns 500 for responseStatusCode.I am not sure what exactly going on. Can someone throw some light on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well, NSHTTPURLResponse will accept any status code. (I use custom status code and it works perfectly. (430 to 440) You should have status code out of the 1xx-9xx range. If your NSLog output 500 it's your server throwing a 500.